# JS: button click to use custom script which uses axios: require is not defined error

Tags: javascript

I have a button which, when clicked, I'd like to execute the `oof` function, which uses `axios`. However the error occurs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

If I remove everything that has to do with `axios` from the `oof`, it would execute (print to console) just fine.

**myscript.js**:

```
const {axios} = require("axios");

const oof = () => {
    console.log("HELLO");

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/oof',
        {message:'hi'})
}
```

**index.html**:

```
  ...
  <div class="oof-button" onclick="oof()">
     oof
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not using node.js and this causes 'require' undefined.

To use axios in Vanilla JS, you can just use the CDN in HTML.
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

For more you can check this article:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-axios-in-vanilla-javascript-2dbf176e08d4